# Select distinct on one column with multiple columns returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

In a table I have 2 versions of cust_id per client; what I am trying to achieve is a list of those products which are only listed under one version of the cust_id to fix the differences and output a report. I do understand that the distinct won't work because I might have the same product for multiple cust_id's.

Am trying to use DISTINICT on one column only to get a list of the distinct product_name for all cust ids.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ([product_name]),
        [cust_id] % 100000 AS 'CustId',
        COUNT([cust_id]) AS 'CustIdCount'
    FROM  [dbo].[solars_solutions_setting]
    WHERE [cust_id] IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        [product_name],
        [cust_id] % 100000,
        [value]
) AS Settings WHERE Settings.CustIdCount < 2
```

Is it possible to output a result having three columns?

- distinct product_name
- list of all cust_id's for that product_name, comma separated (is it possible?)
- custIdCount - which should be 1 (meaning the product is only listed under one version of the cust_id)

Comment: what is your dbms name

Comment: what is the version of sql server

Comment: the dbms am using is sql server 2017 :)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using SQL Server 2017, we can take advantage of `STRING_AGG` here:

```
SELECT
    product_name,
    STRING_AGG(cust_id, ',') AS cust_ids,
    COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id) AS dist_cust_cnt
FROM [dbo].[solars_solutions_setting]
GROUP BY
    product_name
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id) > 1;
```

I chose to retain product names where there be *more* than one `cust_id` present.  In this case, the CSV list `cust_ids` would have more than one value.  Otherwise, it would only have a single value and the call to `STRING_AGG` would not serve much purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`string_agg` is available in this sql sever version.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ([product_name]),
        [cust_id] % 100000 AS 'CustId',
        COUNT([cust_id]) AS 'CustIdCount',
        string_agg(cust_id, ',') as listCust
    FROM  [dbo].[solars_solutions_setting]
    WHERE [cust_id] IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        [product_name],
        [cust_id] % 100000,
        [value]
) AS Settings WHERE Settings.CustIdCount < 2
```

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ([product_name])
       -- [cust_id] % 100000 AS 'CustId',
        COUNT([cust_id]) AS 'CustIdCount'
    FROM  [dbo].[solars_solutions_setting]
    WHERE [cust_id] IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        [product_name],
        [cust_id] % 100000,
        [value]
) AS Settings WHERE Settings.CustIdCount < 2`


this gets me close to my answer but the problem is to output the list of all custids in a separate column. 

string_agg is giving me an exception :/

Comment: if custIds will be on separate column, not rows, you need pivot

Comment: can you provide me with an example pls?